# Uniform Convergence of $(\sin x)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Is the sequence of functions $(\sin(x))^n$ uniformly convergent in $[0,\pi]$? Can you give me a hint or solution, I have already already prove that it is UC in $[0,1]$ but I don't know how to proceed in $[1,\pi]$.

Comment: How did you show it for $[0, 1]$?

Comment: $|(sin(x))^n|\leq |x|^n$ for $x\in [0,1]$

Comment: @Ragnar1204 $|x|^n$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ or even $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: find the pointwise limit of this sequence of functions on $[0,\pi]$. If a sequence is uniformly convergent, then its limit is a continuous function. Is it continuous in this case?

Answer (score 4):

It is not uniformly convergent: At $\pi/2$ we have $\sin(\pi/2)=1$ and thus 
$$
\sin(\pi/2)^n\to 1
$$
What happens everywhere else where $\sin(x)<1$?